# std::list - are the iterators invalidated on move?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

`std::list` iterators have some very nice properties - they remain valid when any other element is removed, when a new element is added and even when 2 lists are swapped ([Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules))!

Considering following code behaviour and that the iterators are implement by a form of pointer to the actual node which doesn't change when the list is moved, my guess is that the iterators are still valid in the new container when a `std::list` is moved, but also I can be in the UB area here by accessing invalid memory which actually has the "expected" value.

```
std::list<int> l1{3, 2, 1};
std::list<int> l2;

auto it = std::prev(l1.end());
std::cout<<l1.size()<<" "<<l2.size()<<" "<<*it<<std::endl;

l2 = std::move(l1);
std::cout<<l2.size()<<" "<<*it<<std::endl;

3 0 1
3 1
```

Is it guaranteed by the standard if the iterators remain valid when `std::list` is moved? What about other containers?

Comment: I've seen similar question before. C++11 explicitly guarantees no invalidation for `swap`, but not for moving. They usually have the same effect, though.

Comment: I would say that they may be invalidated with different allocator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For containers in general, only `swap` guarantees that iterators remain valid (and point into the swapped containers).

For `std::list`, the special member function `splice()` guarantees that iterators retain their expected meaning.

In general, constructing a container from an rvalue doesn't make guarantees about iterators; the only general requirement is that the new container has the "same value" as the container it was constructed from had originally.

(You can imagine debug iterator implementations that store a reference to the container, and that reference would become dangling after a move.)

Comment: Good point with the reference to the container in debug mode. Most implementation do that to help debugging out of range/invalid iterators.

Comment: This debug implementation couldn't possibly meet `swap` complexity requirement (constant).

Comment: @zch: That's true. I think MS iterators use double indirection to allow efficient swaps; it's possible that they would also remain valid under moves.